# Blazor Hybrid: <option> list not updating their position upon window position change, but does so on window refocus

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui, maui-blazor, blazor-hybrid

I'm using the latest version of MAUI and trying to create a Blazor Hybrid app.

The issue I'm facing is that I have a <select> which has some options. Whenever the window changes position, the dropdown list for the options, does not update. This means, after changing the Window position and using the <select>, the dropdown list appears somewhere it should not.

The issue is *not* a problem when just using Blazor WASM, it is however a problem when using a MAUI Blazor App.

A basic code example is this.

```
<label>Select issue showcase.</label>
<select>
    <option disabled hidden selected>Select something.</option>
    @foreach(int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)) 
    {
        <option>@i</option>
    }
</select>
```

I have tried calling StateHasChanged(), but it didn't do anything. I tried using the `<InputSelect>` component from Blazor, also it did not work.

However, I have noticed that whenever I click over to another window (can be anything, Visual Studio, Windows Explorer or whatever), and then try to open the dropdown list again, it now works.

[Video showcasing the issue.](https://i.imgur.com/Wka5lPp.mp4)

Comment: It looks like it's a potential issue for the Maui blazor, you can raise an issue [in this link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).

Comment: I posted the issue, and found out that it's an already reported issue regarding WebView2.
Link for the active issue is here: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2290

So guess it's just a waiting game, for the inevitable fix to be released.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this by forcing a resize on the Maui window (this updates the select position).

In MainPage.xaml.cs we start by listening for any window changes

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
#if WINDOWS
bool _foundWindow;

protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
    base.OnHandlerChanged();

    if (!_foundWindow)
    {
        var window = GetParentWindow();

        if ((window?.Handler?.PlatformView as MauiWinUIWindow)?.GetAppWindow() is var appWindow)
        {
            appWindow.Changed += AppWindow_Changed;
            _foundWindow = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then force a small window resize every time the screen is moved.

```
private void AppWindow_Changed(Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow sender, Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindowChangedEventArgs args)
{


    if (args.DidPositionChange)
    {
        
    


        this.WidthRequest = this.Width + 1;
        this.HeightRequest = this.Height + 1;
        this.WidthRequest = sender.Size.Width;
        this.HeightRequest = sender.Size.Height;




    }
    else if (args.DidSizeChange)
    {
        this.WidthRequest = sender.Size.Width;
        this.HeightRequest = sender.Size.Height;
    }

}

#endif
```

WidthRequest and HeightRequest do not change if the value is the same, hence the increment. DidSizeChange needs to be handled as the resize stops working if not included